# Why is xcolor changing the spacing of my table and how can I fix it?

Tags: tables, color, tabularx

I am creating a table and the following produces the spacing that I am looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

%%% \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

%%% \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lr}
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText                        & TextTextTextTextTextText                      \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText \hfill      Text}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, when I uncomment the two commented lines to get the coloring I want, the spacing changes.
What is going on here? Any ideas how to fix it?

[image: Table with correct spacing but no color]

^ Table from the MWE

[image: Table with correct color but bad spacing]

^ Table with lines uncommented

Comment: never use tabularx like this `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lr}` it has to have at least one X column (unrelated to color)

Comment: Good call, thanks. I was using tabularx with an X column in the actual use case, I had pared it down for the MWE. The spacing issues persist with an X column, although it does end up looking somewhat different.

Comment: yes you can't (in general) use stretch glue in a colortbl table, although that's not documented quite as explicitly as I'd remembered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implied by the code of `colortbl`if not exactly by its documentation, if you use stretch glue in `colortbl`you need to make sure that it totals `0fill`so that it balances the inner stretching done to add the coloured panels.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{center}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText                        & TextTextTextTextTextText                      \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText \hfill
      Text\hspace{\stretch{-1}}\mbox{}}
\end{tabularx}
  
\end{center}

\end{document}
```